# simplehtmldom tag name lowercase and uppercase issue

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am parsing some html code with simplehtmldom, I find some issue, here some short test code:

```
$html =<<<ECHO
<div class="content">content 1</div>
<div class="Content">content 2</div>
ECHO;
$str= str_get_html($html);
foreach($str->find('.content') as $content){
    echo $content.'<br />';  // lost .Content
}
```

So how to solve lowercase and uppercase in simplehtmldom? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refrence http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/#fragment-12 we could first `strtolower` all the elements class.

```
$html =<<<ECHO
<div class="content">content 1</div>
<div class="Content">content 2</div>
ECHO;
$str= str_get_html($html);
foreach($str->find('div') as $divwithclass){
    $divwithclass->class = strtolower($divwithclass->class);
}
foreach($str->find('.content') as $content){
    echo $content.'<br />';
}
```